# Three.js Confused with pointcloud with billboards and sprites

Tags: three.js

I'm testing 10000 points  with texture using the " webgl particle sprites example - snowflakes" and i'm trying to do the same using sprites & spritematerial.
The performance of the sprites aproach is really poor if compare with the first one.

Sprite, as documentation said, is used to see it always towards the camera. But I get the same result using the pointcloudmaterial....

Sprite can do more things with the texture than pointcloudmaterial. But... I dont understand how there is so much perfomance diference.

I have some doubts :

Why is so slow the sprite case?

Is there any way to 'rotate' the pointcloudmaterial or fix it to a given 3D rotation ?

I really appreciate an explanation about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from an expert on how three.js works.  But the reason invoked for using PointCloud (recently renamed Points) always seems to be efficiency.  As mentioned [here](http://www.ianww.com/blog/2012/11/04/optimizing-three-dot-js-performance-simulating-tens-of-thousands-of-independent-moving-objects/), for example.

In general, it makes sense that doing a single operation on a number of identical objects can be faster than doing many operations on objects that aren't known to be identical.  Even if they are identical in practice.